# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor

Tags: python, sqlite

This is My full Code 
idk why i have this error but the data already inserted in sqlite database
the error is 
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor.
[ WARN:1] global C:..\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

```
import cv2 
import sqlite3 

connect = sqlite3.connect('C:///Users///Marvin///Desktop///Opencv-face-detection-python-master///SQL///sql.db')
cur = connect.cursor()

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C://Users/Marvin/Desktop/Opencv-face-detection-python-master/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
id = input("Please Input Your id: ")
name = input("Please Input Your name: ")
nums = 0
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        nums = nums+1
    cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\Marvin\Desktop\Opencv-face-detection-python- 
    master\dataSet\."+str(id)+"."+str(nums)+".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    'cv2.waitKey(100)'

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO user(id,name) Values("+str(id)+",' "+str(name)+" ' )")
    connect.commit()
    cur.close()
```

Comment: You ran `cur.close()` but you put `cur.execute()` in a `while True` loop. You can't execute anymore after you close the cursor.

Comment: i already fix but still have [ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Comment: Different error, open a new question with the code or edit your question.

Comment: Just Move the cur.close() out side of the loop?